# substr instr length for loop

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

good morning guys i have a problem with code i work on Health Care  and complain code must be checkbox but they ask for Report that contain the treatment code which is gonna appear  in database like this 1:15:2:3 etc so i need to calculate each code separate 
i have to count until i get ":" then i need to take the number which can be 1 or 2 digit then making inner join with the other table 
can anyone help me to fix this function and the problem in the loop and get the number for each one

```
create or replace function hcc_get_tcd_codes (p_id in number )
return varchar2 is
x number := 0 ;
y number := 0 ;
z number ;
code1 number ;
code_name varchar2(15);

begin


for i in 0 .. x 
  loop

select length(t.tcd_codes ) into x from hcc_patient_sheet t  where t.id = p_id ;    --- (9)العدد كامل

select instr(tcd_codes, ':') into y from hcc_patient_sheet t where t.id = p_id ;    ---- عدد الكود الاو(3)ل

select instr(tcd_codes, ':')+1 + y into z from hcc_patient_sheet t where t.id = p_id ;     --عدد الكود كامل +1 

enter code here
        i := x -y ;
    select substr(t.tcd_codes,z, instr(tcd_codes, ':')-1) into code1 
--,select substr(t.tcd_codes, 0, instr(tcd_codes, ':')-1) as code2 
  from Hcc_Patient_Sheet t
 where t.id  = 631 ;

 select t.alt_name into code_name from  hcc_complaint_codes t where t.code = code1 ;
select instr(tcd_codes, ':') into y from hcc_patient_sheet t where t.id = p_id ;    ---- عدد الكود الاول

return code_name ;
end loop ;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Often with frequent sounding string processing issues, a wheel has already been invented, and even packaged.

```
select * from table(apex_string.split('THIS:IS:GREAT',':'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Partial `SUBSTR` doesn't seem to be the best option; I'd suggest you to split that colon-separated-values string into row as follows:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1:15:2:3' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '[^:]+', 1, level) one_value
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ':') + 1;

ONE_VALUE
--------------------------------
1
15
2
3

SQL>
```

and use such an option in your query; something like this:

```
select ...
into ...
from some_table t 
where t.id in (select regexp_substr(that_string, '[^:]+', 1, level) one_value
               from dual
               connect by level <= regexp_count(that_string, ':') + 1
              );
```

If it has to be row-by-row, use the above option as a source for the cursor FOR loop, as

```
for cur_r in (select regexp_substr(that_string, '[^:]+', 1, level) one_value
              from dual
              connect by level <= regexp_count(that_string, ':') + 1
             )
loop
  do_something_here
end loop;
```